# Generating Point from Centroid of Polygon falls outside of it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-9.3

I have a feature class of polygons within a geodatabase and I'm trying to generate points based on the centroid of the polygon using the Feature to Point tool in ArcGIS 9.3.

However, I end up with several points that fall just outside of the polygon.

Is this the wrong tool to be using for this application?

Also,  am I making the wrong assumption about this tool generating points from the centroids of polygons?

Comment: Within the tools help dialog box, it says that the a point can be created using the polygon's center of gravity (centroid).  Does the center of gravity not always fall within the polygon?

Comment: The center of gravity can in fact fall outside the polygon. Think of a donut shape, with an empty hole in the middle of the circle polygon. The center of gravity would be there even though the polygon doesn't extend there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [online help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature_To_Point_%28Data_Management%29) indicates that you must check the box to be INSIDE so that a point inside the polygon will be used for the output.

As @DanC commented:

> The center of gravity can in fact fall outside the polygon. Think of a
>   donut shape, with an empty hole in the middle of the circle polygon.
>   The center of gravity would be there even though the polygon doesn't
>   extend there.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But if you leave it unchecked you are telling it to create the point using the centriod (center of gravity) of the polygon.  Is the center of gravity of a polygon not within the polygon?  I guess I don't fully understand the tool and the purpouse of having two options for creating points from polygons.